# Finding all calls to windows api from a programming perspective

Tags: windows, api, hook, apimonitor

I'm looking to develop a program that detects calls to certain Windows API functions and simply records the calling process, call count, and hopefully their arguments, to later mark them as benign or malicious.

The GUI program API monitor is a good example of the functionality I'm trying to achieve. Ideally I would like to track each desired API function individually and get the caller PID and parameters when or after it is used, without user input. The program should be able to run on any windows 7 machine, but can be limited to 32bit applications.

I understand there are several methods of hooking a function, and from my understanding Microsoft detours implements one of these, but I don't know if its the one best suited to what I want to do. I've seen detours, easyhook, deviare API hook, and others mentioned on very old posts, but I have a hard time getting my head around the differences and features of each.

So my question is, given what I'm trying to do, what do you recommend and why?

For reference I'm an intermediate level programmer, but a beginner at Windows programming.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you considered asking the [API Monitor forums](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/forum/1-api-monitor/) instead? Since that is what you need, why not take it from the author?

Comment: I will try there as well, but I'm sure the question is still general enough to be posted here

Comment: It depends on what you need this for. You did not specify whether this is for production or just for research purposes. Microsoft Detours is free if it is not being used in production (the details are in the license so please get the details there if relevant). Microsoft Detours is technical and the lack of support might be a problem. I got it working but it took time to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm part of Nektra [Deviare API Hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) team. Our hooking engine is used by a large number of companies all over the world, in different types of end-user products (e.g.: Anti Virus, Data Loss Prevention, AI, handicapped software, Data Classification, App virtualization).
Deviare-InProc is the MS Detours replacement and Deviare2 has built in all the RPC you need to hook another process and get the calls in your own process.

We continuously fix all reported issues. You can verify it in our GitHub:
https://github.com/nektra/Deviare2
https://github.com/nektra/Deviare-InProc

You can see Deviare2 running in Nektra's [SpyStudio API Monitor](http://www.nektra.com/products/spystudio-api-monitor/).

Detours is an excellent software but very expensive (USD 10k). In addition to this, it completely lacks of support. It can be compared to Deviare InProc,

EasyHook used to be a good start point because it was the only free option. But, now Deviare2 family is open source and EasyHook has a lot of stability issues for the real world.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you make some quite convincing points. Would it be right to say your engine has a steeper learning curve than easyhook?

Comment: EasyHook is also easy and could work fine for a .NET proof of concept, but for production I don't recommend it.

Comment: As a followup, I did end up using Deviare2, and it was exactly what I needed. It's very powerful, fairly easy to use, and there is great support on its github if you post an issue. The only downsides are a lack of up to date tutorials, and that the documentation is a bit brief.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, we'll try to improve the documentation.